# netcore web app - It was not possible to find any compatible framework version

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to use VSCode with .Net Core web applications but I'm stuck at the begining. I installed dotnet sdk 2.0.2 and I created a web application by using yeoman.

I used `dotnet restore` command and after that I used `dotnet run` command. But on `dotnet run` command it keeps saying 'can't find any compatible framework version'. Check the error below.

So how can I run my web app? I tried to change version too but I had same results.

> Using launch settings from /Users/kadir/Documents/Development/WebApplications/firstMvcTutorial/firstMvcCoreWebApp/Properties/launchSettings.json...
>   It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
>   The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.5' was not found.
>     - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
>         /
>     - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.0.5'.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing `"version": "2.0.2"` to `"version": "2.0.0"`?

Comment: Yea I tried, but same result.

Comment: Related post - [How to fix 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.1.2' was not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47349608/465053)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

I downloaded and installed Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.5 [from this link](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/1.0.5-download.md).
After that I changed version to 2.0.0 on global.json. Then I restored dotnet with `dotnet restore` and I run app with `dotnet run`.

But this time I had a problem with `System.Security.Cryptography.Native`.

.
I applied commands below and fixed my problem. Now I can run my web application.

```
brew update
brew install openssl
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

Comment: There is something I am missing here. I thought that .NET Core was portable and that you didn't have to install things. Why isn't referencing the nuget packages enough for it to work? :^)

Comment: It's using openssl for System.Security namespace. So if it's not configured well or if openssl version is not compatible with your application you need to update or reinstall it. So again you need to configure with that code snippet that I shared. Actually dotnet restore should take care of that but I don't know why it's not.