# How to fix 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.1.2' was not found?

Tags: c#, .net-core, mstest

I am seeing this error when I try to run unit tests:

> Testhost process exited with error: It was not possible to find any
>   compatible framework version The specified framework
>   'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.1.2' was not found.
>     - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
>         \
>     - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.1.2'.

How to fix it?

Comment: I see that you've solved the issue now, but for folks who might find this question in the future could you elaborate on what your set up was _before_ installing the package that you mentioned? The error message is making me think that you didn't have the correct version of .NET Core installed.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Installing [DotNetCore.1.0.5_1.1.2-WindowsHosting](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848766) solved the problem for me and my collegues.

Comment: What do you suggest we do if it's a Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 7):

The error tells you that you need to download `Microsoft.NETCore.App`, version `1.1.2`
you can install it through [this](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/1.1.2-download.md) link.

Comment: IIS feature should be already enabled on the target machine before running the installer. Availability of IIS feature is a prerequisite for the sub-part of the installer which installs `Microsoft .NET core Windows Server hosting`.

Answer (score 1):

for me the solution was to install dotnet core 1.1.2.. I had to install the mac version.

https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/1.1.2-download.md