# The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.0' was not found docker in visual studio 7.5 mac

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, docker, asp.net-core

I am trying to run the project on docker on mac os X. The project build successfully however the target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event.

Here is the list of the error

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.0' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      /
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '2.1.0'.
The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.The program '[14] dotnet' has exited with code 131 (0x83).
```

I, have added the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App '2.1.0' in every project. Here is the screen shot of the project.

[image: package description]

**Docker File info**

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY MeroRentalDev.sln ./
COPY Advetisement/Advetisement.csproj Advetisement/
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Advetisement
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Advetisement.dll"]
```

**Dotnet info**
[image: dotnet info]

Updated the docker image to the latest version

```
docker pull microsoft/dotnet
```

Followed the solution from these link but still not able to solve the issue.

[The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.0' was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594020/the-specified-framework-microsoft-aspnetcore-app-version-2-1-0-was-not-foun)

[How to fix 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.1.2' was not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47349608/how-to-fix-microsoft-netcore-app-version-1-1-2-was-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution need to change the docker file

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY MeroRentalDev.sln ./
COPY Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj Auth.API/
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Auth.API
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Auth.API.dll"]
```

Need to change **FROM microsoft/aspnetcore AS base** to **FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk** AS base

Answer (score 0):

What does your Dockerfile & dotnet --info look like?

I had this issue until I re-installed the latest dotnet 2.1.0 SDK, because I wasn't using the multi-arch build and was still using my local development environment which had a 2.1.0-rc1 installation, and the container itself had 2.1.0 installed.

Comment: I, have added the dockerfile info and .net info ..... Please let me know how to solve the issue ... I reinstall it but still same issue